# Enable/disable push notification

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i try to enable/disable push notifications when the user click a button. When the user choose to disable notifications everything is correct, push notifications are not received. But when the user switch again to enable the remote notifications, those are not received. 
In this moment i checked in settings -> notifications and i saw the app is not registered to receive push notifications.

This is my code for the button(to disable):

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.000000)
            {
                UIUserNotificationSettings * settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeNone categories:nil];
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
            }

            else
            {
                //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeNone];
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone];
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
            }
```

This is my code for the button(to enable):

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.000000)
            {
                UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound;
                UIUserNotificationSettings * settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
            }

            else
            {
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
            }
```

In AppDelegate, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, the app is correctly registered for remote notifications:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.000000)
{
    UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound;
    UIUserNotificationSettings * settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

else
{
    //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

Thank you

Comment: It's your server that decides who gets a push. You need to tell the same server you are giving the push token to that they no longer want push.

Comment: thanks for you answer, but can you give me an example. I tried with [[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications]; for disable. It works, but i want to enable the notifications when the user switch again.

Comment: Are you using a service to do push? Where are you sending your device tokens?

Comment: I use  APNS for remote notifications

Comment: yes, when you send a push from a server you need a device token. So for example if you wanted to broadcast push too all of your users you'd need a DB of device tokens to loop over. What I'm saying is you need ignore or delete the row in this DB table for the person when they want to opt out of push.